# Execute code if it is after 1 of April

Tags: date, excel, vba

I have a simple problem but I can't seem to find an anwser.

I want to execute code:

`if` current date < 1 April then
do stuff
else
do other stuff
`end if`

I thought it was pretty easy, since I can get date and format it my way, but problem is when user has different Date format. I did something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rok As Long, rok_kontrola As Date

rok = Format(Date, "yyyy")
rok_kontrola = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

If rok_kontrola < "01-04-" & rok Then
    Me.Controls("rok1").Value = True
Else
    Me.Controls("rok2").Value = True
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
If Date < DateSerial(Year(Date), 4, 1) Then
    Me.Controls("rok1").Value = True
Else
    Me.Controls("rok2").Value = True
End If
```

Comment: DateSerial, that's excacly what I needed. Thank you! Well it's still too soon to click apply button, but I will ;)